# How to allow users to deploy NEAR protocol smart contract on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, web3js, nearprotocol

Getting close to being able to have individual users deploy their own smart contracts from the frontend witn NEAR, but I'm running into an error. First, the code:

```js
const account = await near.account('polluterofminds.testnet');
const res = await axios.get("/api/contract");
  
const contractRaw = res.data;
const uint8 = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(contractRaw))

const result = await account.deployContract(uint8);
console.log(result);
```

When doing this, I get the following error:

```
Error: The transaction contains more then one action, but it was signed with an access key which allows transaction to apply only one specific action. To apply more then one actions TX must be signed with a full access key
```

No idea how to solve this one. As far as I know my `polluterofminds.testnet` account has a full access key and I have signed in with that account.

Anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 4):

Here it is, from an example created a while ago that demonstrates deploying contracts to user accounts as part of a communication protocol

https://github.com/metanear/metanear-web/blob/master/src/Home.js#L96

### UPDATE

*(addressing comment to this answer)*

@JustinHunter there are 2 types of access keys: `FullAccess` that lets you sign transactions with all 8 supported actions and `FunctionCall` access keys that only let you sign transactions with one type, the `FunctionCall` action.

you can see a little more about transactions and actions, keys, etc here:

- https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/transaction
- https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/account#access-keys

and a few relevant words about this restriction in this video:
https://youtu.be/ZM7TCONx9BI?t=2127

Comment: That looks essentially the same as what I have. I still get the same error: 

```
The transaction contains more then one action, but it was signed with an access key which allows transaction to apply only one specific action. To apply more then one actions TX must be signed with a full access key
```

I think this just indicates that I don't know how accounts and access keys should work. The account I am trying to deploy the contract with is the one I signed in with. That seems like it, by default, has full access keys. But maybe not?

Comment: This is super helpful @amgando! Only question I have is how to use the js-sdk to create a full access key? I can't find it documented anywhere, but I'm sure I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you use a function-call-only access key to sign the transaction. To (re-)deploy a contract in NEAR Protocol, you have to use a full-access key. The account in question has full-access and function-call-only keys, but you need to check which one is, ultimately, gets used.

[image: account and keys details on polluterofminds.testnet]